# What is the difference between mtl::mat and mtl::matrix?

Tags: c++, boost, matrix

Specifically, I've noticed that there are two almost identical entries in the MTL (Matrix Template Library) documentation.

[`mtl::mat::inserter`](http://www.simunova.com/docs/mtl4/html/structmtl_1_1mat_1_1inserter.html)
and
 [`mtl::matrix::inserter`](http://www.simunova.com/docs/mtl4/html/structmtl_1_1matrix_1_1inserter.html)

When using `mtl::matrix` my compiler complains that it is not declared, even though the relevant header files are included. I have not run into any problems using `mtl::mat`. Has one of them been deprecated? Are there any differences between the two that I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could glean from the MTL website `mtl::matrix::` is from an older revision of the libraries. `mtl::mat::` would appear to have replaced it in the latest version (Rev 9555 onwards). So if you are using a download of the libraries from before April 2014, this might cause the conflict.